# How do you get user information after uploading a file with the Google API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api

I am working on a side project where user's can upload images of receipts to their Google Drive, and the application will access the text from the images with OCR. I have been tasked to save the information such as file name, file id, file type, file url, etc, in a database so we can access the uploaded picture to use OCR on it. Also, the auth token for a user should be saved in the db, according to some general user information.

How do I go about getting that information? I was able to have the pictures uploaded successfully after authenticating with Google and whatnot, but I have no idea where to find the file id/file url. I have access to file name, file type, and file path (except from what I can tell, it's not where the actual photo is being held in the user's drive).

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can complete my task? I can link my github with the current code if that's allowed. Thank you.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `that information` and `except from what I can tell, it's not where the actual photo is being held in the user's drive`. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal? By this, I would like to try to understand it.

Comment: @Tanaike My friends and I are making an app where we have people upload images of receipt's to Google Drive, and then we access those pictures to get the text off and into another file where we show what was bought and from where.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Although I'm not sure about your actual situation, when you want to retrieve the text values from the uploaded file (image), I think that you can retrieve it using OCR as you say. So I think that it is required to understand about `I was able to have the pictures uploaded successfully after authenticating with Google and whatnot, but I have no idea where to find the file id/file url.`. But I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about the reason of your current issue from it.